# How do I get selected value from Drop Down List?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list (DDL)...

I would usually just use `$('#ddl option:selected').val()`

but I have stored the jQuery object...

```
var myDDL = $('#ddl');
```

I can't figure out how I would use the variable `myDDL` alongside with `option:selected`

Not sure how to word my question really...

Comment: Just use `myDDL.val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to call `val()` on the select object to get the selected value.

```
$('#ddl').val()
```

To get the variable just for the sake of knowing you can use find

```
selectedVal = myDDL.find('option:selected').val();
```

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of select elements, it
>   returns null when no option is selected and an array containing the
>   value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is
>   possible to select more because the multiple attribute is present, [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: I see now. Do you know if there was any reason that I was told to use option:selected when it is unnecessary?

Comment: @user2000236 Depends who you were told to do that by. It could have been someone unfamiliar with how `.val()` worked on dropdowns.

Comment: Not required for given scenario

Comment: I know what has happened now... It must have been .text() that I was told to use option:selected. Thank you all for your help. In the end it was just forgetful memory on my behalf. :) edit: i will tick when timer runs out.

Comment: Yes, for text that method is used, you recalled the memory within no time :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Call this below function to see the effects.

----------------------- JS-Code -----------------------

```
TestFunction();

function TestFunction() {
    var myDDL = $('#ddl');
    var selectedVal = myDDL.find('option:selected').val();
    alert(selectedVal);
}
```

-------------------- HTML Code --------------------------

```
<div id="divTest">
        <select id="ddl">
        <option>one</option>
        <option selected="selected">two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select id="ddlCountry" name="ddlCountry">
<option selected="selected" value="1">India
</option>
<option value="2">USA
</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

$('#ddlCountry').val()

I hope this helps. If this does resolve your problem, please mark the post as answered.

Thanks,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 myDDL.find('option:selected').val();
```

---

As myDDL is a jQuery object, so you can use `.find()` method to get the selected value.